# I have diversity index values and I wish to test for statistical significance between the zones readings. How can I statistically analyse this?

Tags: r, excel, ecology, diversity

[image: Table showing diversity data]

I have produced a graph for each Zone, x axis = years, y axis = diversity.
I would primarily like to analyse the difference in diversity between the zones, but would also be interested in analysing the difference between sites. Please just ask if I should include any other information or what have you. (I produced the diversity results in R I just struggled making the plots I was after so I moved the data into excel for that bit)

[image: example of graph]

Comment: What is the actual research question ? If you look at year 2013 and 2015 there is a pretty good change the sites are the same (in terms of statistical significance), whereas in 2019 they would probably be significantly different. What is the role of time in your research question ? One approach could be an ANCOVA on the whole dataset with an interaction where the interaction would indicate a difference in slopes for a fitted line for each site, or perhaps an ANOVA for each year ? Also what role does Site play in your research question ?

Comment: It is variable,  basically I was given a data set and had to form an SPF from that researching whatever I choose. I wanted to research biodiversity.  so the question is still in the air but it is a long the lines of "the difference in the Biodiversity of reef zones" but this could be adapted for sites instead and change over time

Comment: There were 3 different sites,  A has a moderate fishing pressure, B has the least and C has the largest

Comment: @Robert Long I am unsure what you mean how would I run an ANCOVER on the data?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach here would be to use a type of ANCOVA. The model in R would look like:

```
lm(Diversity ~ Year * Zone, data = myData)
```

assuming that Site is not relevant.

To be honest I'm not sure you have enough data for this to be useful.

A better approach might be to work with the properties of the diversity statistic but that isn't something I can help with.

Comment: Okay thanks, what do you mean by work with the properties of the diversity statistic? I know this isn't your field so thanks for your help so far

Comment: Maybe you can construct confidence intervals based on the raw underlying data. Something like that.

Comment: Can confidence intervals be produced in R? i would assume i use the raw data

Comment: Yes but I would think it has to be done with reference to the way the diversity index is computed.